# Patch Arm binary with Ida

Tags: ida, arm, patching

In Ida I can patch binary that run on x86 , but not binary that run on Arm.

How can I simply patch binary , change assembly(not only hex) and save to new binary file

Answer (score 1):

[Keypatch](http://www.keystone-engine.org/keypatch/) is a plugin for IDA that uses keystone to assemble instructions for patching. It supports ARM. Once you've patched the IDB you can go to Edit -> Patch Program -> Apply Patches to Input File